# Trying to use MongoDB with Google Colab by placing the data directory on my Google Drive

Tags: python, mongodb, google-colaboratory, drive

I want to use MongoDB from Google Colab.
So I need to be able to put my MongoDB data directory on my Google Drive so I don't lose my data from one session to another, but I cannot change the data folder.

1. Mount Google Drive

```py
# Mount Google Drive
from google.colab import drive drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

2. Install MongoDB on Colab environment

```py
!apt-get install mongodb
```

3. Stopping the MongoDB service

```py
!service mongodb stop
```

4. Relaunching the MongoDB service with parameter dbpath to specify the new path

```py
!service mongodb start --dbpath /content/drive/MyDrive/mongodb
```

5. Using pumongo lib to access database after

```py
import pymongo from pymongo
import MongoClient client = MongoClient()
client.list_database_names() # which return ['admin', 'local']
```

The problem with my code above is that I can query my Mongo database, but mongodb will still use the path specified in the mongodb.conf file.

```py
# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
```

Then I tried to change the path in the mongodb.conf file to

```
# Where to store the data.
dbpath=content/drive/MyDrive/mongodb
```

But then I get an error when I restart the mongodb service

```
* Starting database mongodb
    ...fail!`
```

What am I forgetting or not doing right at all please?

Thanks for your help